# C#: Wrong DateTime format passed to front end

Tags: javascript, c#

So I am returning a date value from my backend API.

This is my model:

```
public class Sales {
    ....
    public DateTime DateCreated {get;set;}
}
```

I return it from my `Controller`:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public async Task<Sales> GetSales() {
    .....
    Sales s = await GetSalesForTheUser();
    return s;
}
```

The `DateTime` value returned by the `Controller` is missing the `Z` at the end of it.

The returned value is: `2021-07-27T05:23:41.937` this is wrong because when I parsed it in the Javascript, it is treated as local date time. When I added `Z` at the end of it (`2021-07-27T05:23:41.937Z`) then this is right. The date parsing from the Javascript is giving me the correct value.

How can I fix the correct parsing value from my backend (C#)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using NewtonJson:

Add the package to your project

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="..." />
```

and you can achieve it by adding some configurations to your Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
    
  // Configure controllers.
  services.AddControllers()
      .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
      {
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter()
        {
          DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"
        });
      });

  ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have example for `.Net`?

Comment: @AlvinStefanus which framework are you using?

Comment: `.Net` not `.NetCore`

Comment: I got it from here https://forums.asp.net/t/2084573.aspx?UTC+Date+is+being+deserialized+to+server+local+time+when+PUT+and+PATCH+

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the problem is within your DateTime object's `Kind`, and not the serialization.

If the `DateTime.Kind` is either `Local` or `Unspecified`, serializing this in ISO8601 will omit the timezone information (in your case Z, which indicates UTC).

To fix this, first start by trying to specify the kind of your `DateTime` before returning the data. See here how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.specifykind?view=net-5.0.

If that works, inspect your service, and see if you are correctly interpreting the data returned to populate the property `Sales.DateCreated`, and ensure this is in UTC.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change it on the backend, then create another property in
your Sales class like "DataCreatedFormated" of type string and  `public string DateCreatedFormated => DateCreated.ToString(format);` where "format" is one from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0).
I suggest 'u' format.

Comment: DateCreated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss z") can be a solution to this problem

Comment: I would never serialize a date to anything other than ISO8601 - not sure what the fascination is with custom formatting!

Comment: @phuzi You don't have to hate us, we are giving an exact answer to the question. And I specified what format he should use, next time please read to the end after you comment with haste just to say something very "smart".

Comment: Disagreement is not the same as hatred! I've retracted my comment regarding the article but I'll let the other one stand though because it's still valid.